# android webRTC receiving call with no audio

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, microphone, webrtc-android

I am implementing VoIP with Native Android WebRTC lib. I have managed to make a call from the Android app to the Browser. I can hear and talk as expected. But when I try to call from the Browser to the Android app, I am not able to hear or talk on the connected line. Creating a `peerConnection`, `setRemoteDescription`, `setLocalDescription`, creating an `Answer` all happens as expected (theoretically).

PS: I see a little icon on the top of my Android device that the microphone is in use when I make a call. But I do not see anything like this when I am receiving a call.

I was wondering if someone can help me to understand if

1. The `sdp` which is set as LocalDescription after creating Answer needs the IP address and ICE candidates included in it? If yes, How do I include them as I see no ICE candidates and the IP address is 0.0.0.0 IP4
2. Do I have to do anything specific to handle the microphone and speaker apart from using standard native WebRTC lib.

Comment: Audio permission is a Runtime permission . Do you have Audio runtime permission granted ?

Comment: Yes, I have a check for `RECORD_AUDIO` and `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`. and only when they are granted, I start with the process.

Comment: Well you need to debug the code . Check the Audio configuration in `peerConnectionClient` . If you are unable to find the culprit then You can pick a sample from GitHub and change Searver urls and check with the sample .

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to debug the code and find the culprit. but I have no success and hence this Question. On the other hand.. can you share a sample github.

Comment: If you find the culprit then add the code block with Question . Try googling `webrtc android sample github`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing a similar issue, here is the solution I found.

In the SDP which was created after `createAnswer()` and to be set as LocalDescription, I found that the value was `m=audio 0...`. This does not sound correct. Also, it was missing  `a=setup:active` in the SDP.

After lots of debugging, I found that the flags
`options.disableEncryption = true` and `options.disableNetworkMonitor = true` set as options while creating PeerConnectionFactory were stopping the audio.
So removing these flags resolved my issue.